# Fullpage.js navigation issue

Tags: jquery, scroll, fullpage.js

https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/qqabrp

on this example if I set these two values in fullpage

`bigSectionsDestination: ".section",`

`normalScrollElements: '.section',`

> new fullpage('#fullpage', {
>     sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],
>     bigSectionsDestination: ".section",
>     normalScrollElements: '.section',
>      navigation: true,
>   });

because my section size is more then viewport and I also want to scroll on it and also **navigation: true**,  then navigation using mouse scroll is not working

Comment: May be my issue, can you explain what you your problem is

Comment: I am making fullpage gallery and in all section I have one image which size is more then viewport, so user can scroll image and navigation also,
but section scroll and navigation are not working if fullsize it indicate section scroll only

Comment: Sorry, I dont think it can be done,  check the issue listed https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/614

Answer (score 0):

From the [the fullpage.js documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js):

> **bigSectionsDestination:** (default null) Defines how to scroll to a section which size is bigger than the viewport. By default fullPage.js scrolls to the top if you come from a section above the destination one and to the bottom if you come from a section below the destination one. Possible values are `top`, `bottom`, `null`.

Possible values are only `top`, `bottom`, `null`.

Comment: yes but still top, bottom, null  is not helpful, if I will update in question to null then what is the solution? scrolloverflow =true with scrolloverflow.js, then scroll not become smooth :-)

Comment: Yeah you can use `scrollOverflow:true`